# How can I evenly distribute columns in a DataGrid in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, view, adobe

I have 16 columns in a DataGrid in my Flex app. The first 15 look fine, with the column, simply containing the text, but the last one has a lot of extra space. Essentially, the columns are just big enough to fit the first 15 and all that extra space is tacked onto the 16th column.

How can I evenly distribute the space over each column?

```
<mx:DataGrid x="127" y="9" id="view"
                 dataProvider = "{currentBuffer}" width="497" height="480">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="0" dataField="col0" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="1" dataField="col1" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="2" dataField="col2" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="3" dataField="col3" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="4" dataField="col4" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="5" dataField="col5" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="6" dataField="col6" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="7" dataField="col7" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="8" dataField="col8" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="9" dataField="col9" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="A" dataField="colA" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="B" dataField="colB" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="C" dataField="colC" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="D" dataField="colD" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="E" dataField="colE" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="F" dataField="colF" draggable="false" sortable="false" resizable="false"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually setting the [width](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#width) on the columns using the width property?

You could easily use updateDisplayList to calculate the size of each column, either by creating your own wrapper component or by extending the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of each column to `6.25%` - of give 6% to first 15 and 10% to the last one.

Comment: Are you sure that will that work? The DataGridColumn does not have a percentageWidth property, and I thought setting width to a percentage in MXML just did some magic in the background w/ percentageWidth.

Comment: @www The column class doesn't have percentWidth, but iirc, I've  given percent values to widths of columns in the past and it worked.